# ERROR: Error importing 'System tables' objects (Ecommerce - SKU) in Kentico

Tags: sql-server, kentico

I am having problems importing from a file created by Kentico running locally using sa loggin, to an instance of Kentico running at a hosted site using a hosting space login.

The following error occurs when trying to import an export file.  Kentico version is 7.31  at export and import location.

```
> ERROR:  Error importing 'System tables' objects (Ecommerce - SKU)
Message: [ TableManager.UpdateDocumentViews() ] An error occurred. Original exception: [DataConnection.HandleError]: Query:
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular_NodeSiteID_DocumentCulture_NodeID] ON [View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular]
(
[NodeSiteID] ASC,
[DocumentCulture] ASC,
[NodeID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular_ClassName_NodeSiteID_DocumentForeignKeyValue_DocumentCulture] ON [View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular]
(
[ClassName] ASC,
[NodeSiteID] ASC,
[DocumentForeignKeyValue] ASC,
[DocumentCulture] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF)
: caused exception: Index cannot be created on view 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular' because the underlying object 'CMS_Class' has a different owner. Stack Trace: at CMS.DataEngine.TableManager.RefreshDocumentViews()
at CMS.DataEngine.TableManager.RefreshCustomViews(String tableName)
at CMS.CMSImportExport.ImportProvider.UpdateObject(SiteImportSettings settings, GeneralizedInfo infoObj, Boolean siteObject, DataSet ds, TranslationHelper th, Boolean updateChild, Int32 targetSiteId, ProcessObjectEnum process, Dictionary`2 importedParentIDs, List`1 postProcessList, List`1 affectedObjects, BaseInfo parentObject, Boolean postProcessing)
at CMS.CMSImportExport.ImportProvider.ImportObjects(SiteImportSettings settings, DataSet ds, String objectType, Boolean siteObjects, TranslationHelper th, Boolean importChild, ProcessObjectEnum processType, Dictionary`2 importedParentIDs)

ERROR:  Error during import process
Message: [ TableManager.UpdateDocumentViews() ] An error occurred. Original exception: [DataConnection.HandleError]: Query:
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular_NodeSiteID_DocumentCulture_NodeID] ON [View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular]
(
[NodeSiteID] ASC,
[DocumentCulture] ASC,
[NodeID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular_ClassName_NodeSiteID_DocumentForeignKeyValue_DocumentCulture] ON [View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular]
(
[ClassName] ASC,
[NodeSiteID] ASC,
[DocumentForeignKeyValue] ASC,
[DocumentCulture] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF)
: caused exception: Index cannot be created on view 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined_Regular' because the underlying object 'CMS_Class' has a different owner. Stack Trace: at CMS.CMSImportExport.ImportProvider.ImportObjects(SiteImportSettings settings, DataSet ds, String objectType, Boolean siteObjects, TranslationHelper th, Boolean importChild, ProcessObjectEnum processType, Dictionary`2 importedParentIDs)
at CMS.CMSImportExport.ImportProvider.ImportObjectType(SiteImportSettings settings, String objectType, Boolean siteObject, TranslationHelper th, ProcessObjectEnum process, Dictionary`2 importedParentIDs)
at CMS.CMSImportExport.ImportProvider.ImportObjectsData(SiteImportSettings settings)
```

I note some of the table names at the site have different owners, some dbo and some under my user login.  I expect this is because it is my user loggin in the Kentico app.config. I use the same login when connecting with Management Studio.

I think the dbo objects must have been created by the restoration of a database  ( I am thinking they cant have been created by Kentico install as that would have been logged in using my login )

I guess one work around would be to stop using the export feature - and only restore databases,  but the export feature is handy.  We would like to get it working if we can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing the default schema for the user name to dbo, in SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 2):

What is the value set as DB objects schema in Site Manager -> Settings - > System?
This setting should match the DB schema and also, all the object should have it the same. I would recommend to unify the tables and views schema to have one and the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you same installation on both machines? This issue occur when you don't have installed all modules as on origin machine (even if you don't use them). Try to exlude all Ecommerce object of System tables when you configure Import.